# About basic HTML attributes

Tags: html, css, image

I cannot get an image to the size I want. I've tried changing the attributes inside the image tag in many ways but the problem is the image is always displayed at the original size.

I've tried this:

```
<img src="url" alt="some text" style="width:40px;height:40px">
```

I've tried this:

```
<img src="url"; alt="some text"; style="width:40px";"height:40px">
```

And in many other ways. Not that it changed anything. the image is always displayed at full size. I just cant get it right. Also, to clarify, the image in question is stored locally in the same folder as the .html file.

Also, if you guys could clarify some things about the "background-color:#FFFFFF" attribute it would help me a lot. I noticed that some times it simply will not work, the background will appear as blank even if I get the syntax right. Should I take some considerations before using it?

Thanks.

Comment: That seems to work just fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/6borf5j0/. It would also be more ideal to keep things like width and height in a css file as not to junk up your markup anymore than you have to.

Comment: try without the `style` like this `<img src="url" alt="some text" width=40 height=40>`

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried this:
>
> `<img src="url" alt="some text" style="width:40px;height:40px">`

This seems right. As long as the url is valid.

Here is a `400x400`px image resized to `100x100`px.

```html
<img 
  src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400"
  style="width:100px; height:100px;"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be sure that you check your url, as if one small symbol is wrong it wont work.

Or you could try to make the position absolute.

For Example:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" 
style="width:300px;height:300px;position:absolute;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try it with `max-width:40px` and check the provided `src` url